# How do I store a file on my Android emulated device and then access it from my program?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-file

I am looking to manually add a [text] file to my Android emulated device, and then retrieve it as a file when I am running my program. I can access files in my own C drive in testing, but obviously I cannot access the C drive of my PC on my emulator. 
I can get into my devide on file explorer [device].adk/data and the folder list is:
- app
- benchmarktest
- misc
- nativetest

And how I am trying to retrieve the file is through:

```
public static final String MY_FILE = "[directoryhere]";
```

My question is: which folder would I store my file in, and what directory would I retrieve it from?

Alternatively, I have tried to store it on my localhost and access the directory as:

```
public static final String MY_FILE = "http://[myip]/files/my.file";
```

however, when I try to retrieve it I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\[myip]\files\my.file (The network name cannot be found)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try these two methods to store your files in your emulator

1. the easiest way is that just do **drag and drop** i mean when u
   start    your emulator drag your file and drop it and it will save
   it in your    emulator than you can easily access that
2. you can use the ADB via Terminal to pass the file From Desktop to Emulator.

> Copy from desktop to emulator:
>
> adb push < local > < remote >
>
> Copy from emulator to desktop:
>
> adb pull < remote > < local >
>
> Here < local > is path of file / folder on your desktop and < remote> is
>   path of file / folder on your emulator.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> adb push foo.txt /sdcard/foo.txt
>
> foo.txt will be pushed (copied) to the emulator.

**for more information** 
[Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#copyfiles)